# Diffrances in Localized Versions of the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, localization, internationalization, .net-framework-version

I am wondering what the differences are in [localised versions of the.net frameworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480240.aspx) running under application the same culture code (i.e. application is not localised).

So far I understand that:

- Exception Messages are localised so appear in foreign language
- The Names of countries in the framework are localised

is there anything else to be aware of?

*Update: I am writing winforms for the 3.5 framework*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with satellite assemblies.  You can see what *can* be localized with Reflector.  Click the Resources node for an assembly and select the .resources entry.  There's rather a lot of it, but I only see strings for exception messages and property descriptions visible from the Properties window.  Country names are already localized.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha to be aware of is the string representations of numbers. For example, in a Danish culture, which uses "," as its decimal separator, "3.141" will parse to 3141, as "." is interpreted as a thousands separator.

Additionally, DateTime.ToString() returns localized representations of data, and DateTime.Parse() parses in a localized manner.

If you are reading data from a source other than your own application or sending it to one, it is highly recommended that you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as this will be consistent across locales. For data displayed to the user, stick to the local culture.

Comment: Good point however if the app is using the same culture code this should be ok as it will still be formatted to UK

Comment: I don't quite understand why this is -1. Can you provide some feedback?

Comment: -1 was not given by me. However although the point you made was valid I guess did not answer the question. You are referring to application localisation rather than the differences inside localised versions of the framework.